# Angular Material2 Slide-toggle inside Menu

Tags: angular, material-design

Is there any proper way to display a Slide-toggle `<mat-slide-toggle>` inside Menu `<mat-menu>`

Furthermore, when I tap on the Slide-toggle, the menu disappears. Is there any way to prevent that from happening.

```
<mat-menu #menuSettings="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
      <span>Dark</span>
      <mat-slide-toggle></mat-slide-toggle>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>face</mat-icon>
      <span>Register now</span>
    </button>
</mat-menu>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do that by adding `(click) = "$event.stopPropagation()"` to the `<mat-slide-toggle>` element:

```
<mat-menu #menuSettings="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
      <span>Dark</span>
      <mat-slide-toggle (click)="$event.stopPropagation();"></mat-slide-toggle>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>face</mat-icon>
      <span>Register now</span>
    </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: I guess you meant adding this to mat-menu tag that may work

Comment: Doesn't work if you put it at the mat-menu level. Works if you put it in the mat-slide-toggle (ideally, as _one_ of the _several_ things in your click handler) but then toggling didn't reflect the correct value for me (but I'm using [checked] against an ngrx variable; YMMV with [(ngModel)] or [formControlName]).